# Альтернатива rand в СИ

Tags: c, linux, случайные-числа

Столкнулся с замечательной функцией rand при построении программы на СИ в ОС Linux. Знаю, что нужно инициализировать генератор с помощью srand.

Но у меня запускается одновременно несколько копий моей программы. В связи с чем все программы получают одно и тоже число.

Есть ли альтернатива rand. которая позволит при одновременном запуске программы (т.е. несколько потоков) каждому экземпляру получить разное число?

Comment: У srand параметр есть. пусть они инициализируют датчик не просто временем, а например добавляют к нему свой pid или другое число, которое уникально для каждого экземпляра

Comment: Если у Вас Linux, то можно просто читать /dev/random или /dev/urandom.

Comment: @Mike интересная идея, попробую.

Comment: @kff можете дать примерчик, буду очень признателен.

Comment: @nerik только все таки предлагаю не просто прибавлять pid а что нибудь более интересное делать. например умножать время на pid. А то может случится что с разницей в 1 секунду у вас запустятся 2 процесса с идущими подряд pid. и суммы будут равны :)

Comment: @nerik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572366/how-to-use-dev-random-or-urandom-in-c.

Comment: @Mike отличная идея, спасибо. Все получилось))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У srand есть параметр - инициализационное число "случайной" последовательности. Обычно его задают как текущее время. При одновременном старте двух процессов время одинаковое и последовательность получается одинаковая. Вам надо сделать это число уникальным для каждого запускаемого процесса. Для этого можно использовать, например, текущее время умноженное на ID текущего процесса. Или использовать какую нибудь другую уникальную характеристику процесса.

Answer (score 2):

Если не принципиально и возможно использовать c++11, то работа со псевдослучайными последовательностями там значительно расширена. Также для инициализации в c++11 можно использовать все тоже время, но взятое, скажем, в наносекундах, что даже в Вашем случае даст разные последовательности.